# Adding a line to a scatter plot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot, raster

I have a scatter plot of two raster images.  What I need is to create a triangle around the scatter plot. So far what I have it

```
minveg <- quantile(veg, 0.01, na.rm=TRUE)
mintemp <- quantile(temps, 0.01, na.rm=TRUE)
plot(veg, temps, xlab='veg', ylab='temp')
abline(h=mintemp, v=minveg)
```

This give me the following image

[image]

What I need is a third line that goes along the scatter plot and completes the triangle with the other two lines.  I'm sure I could add an equation just looking at it and fit my best idea but I have to do this for hundreds of images and was looking for a more automated way to do it.  Any suggestions are helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Where should the third line cut the other lines?

Comment: That is what I am having trouble figuring out.   The line should go along the edge of the data points.  That  edge of the scatter plot should dictate where the line is and not where it intersects the other two.

Comment: It's not that difficult to adapt a regression line even to many plots. Please give a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use quantile regression for this.

```
 library(quantreg)

 # example data
 set.seed(0)
 x = rnorm(1000)
 y = rnorm(1000) - x


 minx <- quantile(x, 0.01, na.rm=TRUE)
 miny <- quantile(y, 0.01, na.rm=TRUE)
 plot(x,y, xlim=c(-6,6), ylim=c(-6,6))
 abline(h=minx, v=miny, col='red') 
 abline(rq(y ~ x, tau=.99), col='blue')
```